# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice') using react class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

I am learning react and i was trying to make a react class based component in which i am trying to fetch data from articles array that has data of news articles such as title,description, urlToimage, url. **i was trying to cut short the title and description string to a maximum length of 40 and 80 respectively and i tried doing this with the use of slice** as you can see but met with the error mentioned below. I also made sure that the title and description are of string or array datatypes to avoid any datatype incurred errors both title and description are written as **"title" : "**content inside**"**. Rest of the code was running fine without slice and was showing all the data as intended. I don't know if the syntax have changed or not as i am following a tutorial from 2021.

```js
{this.state.articles.map((elements) => {
            let title = elements.title;
            let description = elements.description;
           
            return <div className="col-md-4 my-3" key={elements.url}>
              <NewsItem title={title.slice(0,45)} description={description.slice(0,80 )} imageUrl={elements.urlToImage} newsUrl={elements.url}></NewsItem>
            </div>
          })}

react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')
```

Comment: console.log elements.title and you will see if the title is there or not and then you can do like `title = elements.title || 'defult value'` so if the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the title you're getting in response is `undefined`.

```js
{this.state.articles.map((elements) => {
  let title = elements?.title || ""; // Either this approach
  let description = elements?.description || ""; // Either this approach

  return <div className="col-md-4 my-3" key={elements.url}> // Or use optional chaining 
    <NewsItem title={title?.slice(0,45)} description={description?.slice(0,80 )} imageUrl={elements.urlToImage} newsUrl={elements.url}></NewsItem>
  </div>
})}
```

You can either use `or(||)` operator to initialize title as an empty string or use optional chaining as shown in example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that one or all of the `articles` in your state contain `description` or `title` as `null`.
This is why you are getting this error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')`

Simply add `null/undefined` check before slicing and it should work.

If you use optional chaining this can be achieved as below.

```
{this.state.articles.map((elements) => {
            let title = elements.title;
            let description = elements.description;
           
            return <div className="col-md-4 my-3" key={elements.url}>
              <NewsItem title={title?.slice(0,45)} description={description?.slice(0,80 )} imageUrl={elements.urlToImage} newsUrl={elements.url}></NewsItem>
            </div>
          })}
```

Or for without optional chaining

```
{this.state.articles.map((elements) => {
                let title = elements.title;
                let description = elements.description;
               
                return <div className="col-md-4 my-3" key={elements.url}>
                  <NewsItem title={title?title.slice(0,45):""} description={description ? description.slice(0,80 ) : ""} imageUrl={elements.urlToImage} newsUrl={elements.url}></NewsItem>
                </div>
              })}
```